# htaccess 301 redirects, one works, one doesn't

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, redirect

Can someone please explain to me why

```
Redirect 301 /elite5m-hd-gold-off-road-gps-by-lowrance-p-58323.html http://newwebsite.com/elite-5m-hd-gold-gps-by-lowrance-lowrance-p-30.html
```

works just fine, but not:

```
Redirect 301 /accessories-gps-mapping-c-1203_1184.html http://newwebsite.com
```

Here are the rewrite rules that I have in place

```
 RewriteRule ^(.*)-p-(.*).html$ product_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
 RewriteRule ^(.*)-c-(.*).html$ index.php?cPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
 RewriteRule ^(.*)-m-([0-9]+).html$ index.php?manufacturers_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
 RewriteRule ^(.*)-pi-([0-9]+).html$ popup_image.php?pID=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
 RewriteRule ^(.*)-t-([0-9]+).html$ articles.php?tPath=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
 RewriteRule ^(.*)-a-([0-9]+).html$ article_info.php?articles_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
 RewriteRule ^(.*)-pr-([0-9]+).html$ product_reviews.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
 RewriteRule ^(.*)-pri-([0-9]+).html$ product_reviews_info.php?products_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
 RewriteRule ^(.*)-i-([0-9]+).html$ information.php?info_id=$2&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: I don't see a problem with that rule. Are you sure there is nothing else in your .htaccess breaking it? Is that all you have in your file?

Comment: The rule should work, do you have any other rules in your htaccess?

Comment: I just added the rewrite rules that are in effect but the redirects are above the rewrite rules. I do have a pretty busy htaccess file but  what I've posted is everything that i believe would be directly related to what's going on here.